# hadoop version - fairscheduler-statedump.log (No such file or directory)

Tags: hadoop, linux-mint

I tried to install hadoop-3.2.0 on linux mint. Everything is going fine. Also java 11.0.2 is installed like this:

```
$ java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+7-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

when I use this command `hadoop version`, I get this error:

```
$ hadoop version
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/hadoop-3.2.0/logs/fairscheduler-statedump.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:158)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.<clinit>(VersionInfo.java:37)
Hadoop 3.2.0
Source code repository https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git -r e97acb3bd8f3befd27418996fa5d4b50bf2e17bf
Compiled by sunilg on 2019-01-08T06:08Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum d3f0795ed0d9dc378e2c785d3668f39
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop-3.2.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.2.0.jar
```

It seems hadoop is properly installed but something is wrong with `log4j`.
May I ask you to help me to solve this error?

Update:
I should mention that I tried to install a version before hadoop-3.2.0 means hadoop-3.1.2 and everything seems fine.
So I guess this is the problem related to java v11.0.2 and hadoop-3.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem bause I install hadoop by root user and then run hadoop command by hadoop user. I just slove the problem by changing the owner and group of hadoop directory.

```
sudo chown -R hadoop:hadoop hadoop-3.2.0/

$ hadoop version

Hadoop 3.2.0
Source code repository https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git -r e97acb3bd8f3befd27418996fa5d4b50bf2e17bf

Compiled by sunilg on 2019-01-08T06:08Z

Compiled with protoc 2.5.0

From source with checksum d3f0795ed0d9dc378e2c785d3668f39
This command was run using /opt/hadoop-3.2.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.2.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue, but I figured it was due to different Java versions. I had originally installed JDK 11 but changed JDK 8 since Hadoop 3.x is not compliant with anything after 8 (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions).

However, I am still facing this issue after changing to JDK 8. The solution offered assumes we created a Hadoop user, but I do not have permission to create another user on my server (work computer).

Should I change ownership to root? I do have some sudo privileges.

Answer (score -1):

I create log directory in /usr/local/hadoop and grant permission to my hadoop account.

```
/usr/local/hadoop$ sudo mkdir logs
/usr/local/hadoop$ sudo chown -R hadoop logs
```

Comment: As of now, it will not solve my problem and I found this:
`Java 11 support is now in progress:  HADOOP-15338 - Support Java 11 LTS in Hadoop OPEN` at [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions]